# Value equality for struct keys and reference equality for class keys in a dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, reference, equality

I'm implementing a generic dictionary. I want the `TKey` to be either a struct or a class. If it's a structure I want to compare keys by value, otherwise by reference.

I can't use neither `Object.Equals` (only works with structs) nor `Object.ReferenceEquals` (only works with reference types). What method do I use to test for equality then?

`==` operator would probably solve this issue but I can't use it without specifying any constraints for the key (`where TKey : ...`). What interfaces should I declare?

Comment: why `can't use neither Object.Equals (only works with structs)`? documentations says the opposite: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just to clear up confusion: You **want** to compare this way right (Equals for structs & reference equality for classes) ? It is not because you feel you **need** to?

Comment: @ASh
"If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result."

Comment: @Alex
I don't really _need_ to do that. I just want it to work like the built-in generic `Dictionary<T>`.

Comment: The `System.Object.Equals()` method works equally well for value and reference types. Of course, either _might_ have overridden the method, producing something other than a strict member-by-member value comparison (value types) or a strict reference equality comparison (reference types). Please clarify what the real goal here is and what your limitations are. It's not really clear what you're asking or what would solve your problem.

Comment: _"I just want it to work like the built-in generic Dictionary<T>"_ -- I assume you mean "the build-in generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`". And if you want it to work just like that, why not just use **that**?

Comment: @PeterDuniho
I only want the key comparison to work like in the `Dictionary<T>`, other than that it's a different implementation. However, your previous comment is the answer I was looking for. For some reason I assumed that `Equals()` is _always_ a value eqality check (I'm pretty sure I tried to look it up on MSDN). Would you mind converting this comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Okay, I've posted an answer the effect of my comment above. Glad we could figure out what you needed. :)

Comment: Be careful if you only use a reference comparison with objects. Many objects override 'Equals<type>', and you would be ignoring this. This could lead to potential bugs later if someone does something like 'var myKey = dict.Keys.FirstOrDefault(key => key.Equals(someObject));' because there could be many keys in your dictionary that are 'equal' according to the class implementation.

Comment: @RufusL
Yes, I realise that. My intention was to use the default implementation of `Equals` and I was worried that it would force classes' instances that don't have it overriden to be compared by value anyway. This is not how `Equals` actually work apparently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't use neither Object.Equals (only works with structs) nor Object.ReferenceEquals (only works with reference types).

It seems you may simply be mistaken about how these work. The [`System.Object.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) method implementation works equally well (no pun intended) whether dealing with a value type or a reference type.

For value types, it does a field-by-field comparison. If the two values being compared are the same type, and each of their fields have the same value, then they are considered equal.

For reference types, it simply uses reference equality, as you seem to want.

Note that types can override this method, so the actual implementation used *could* be different from the above. For example, the `string` type overrides the method, so that two strings which are not the same instance can still compare as equal. But by default, the above is what happens.

Finally I'll note that if what you want is a behavior that works *exactly like* the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class, it may well be that the best solution is to just use that class. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following in your class:

```
public class MyCustomDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private static readonly Func<TKey, TKey, bool> _equalityComparer;

    // ... other stuff

    static MyCustomDictionary()
    {
        if (typeof(TKey).IsClass)
            _equalityComparer = (lhs, rhs) => Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs)
        else
            _equalityComparer = (lhs, rhs) => lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    // ... other stuff

}
```

And use this equality comparer for comparisons.

The way this is normally done though, is by using an equality comparer [`IEqualityComparer<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
public class MyCustomDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> _equalityComparer;

    // ... other stuff

    public MyCustomDictionary()
    {
        _equalityComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public MyCustomDictionary(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _equalityComparer = comparer;
    }

    // ... other stuff

}
```

This is what is done e.g. in the regular BCL `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and other collections that need to do equality comparisons.

If you do not have very special needs (like I initially thought when I read your question), you should use the standard way of doing it with an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`.

Comment: Well, this _is_ a solution, though I don't really want to explicitly check whether the key is a reference type or not.

Comment: This happens only once ever in the lifetime of the a specific type. I.e this does **not** happen *everytime* an instance of the dictionary is created. It is a one-time static initialization thing

Answer (score 1):

.NET generic dictionary using Equals and GetHashCode methods, that are virtual and available for both a struct and a class. So you can simply do the same, and just override those methods in you struct:

```
public struct KeyStructure 
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // your implementation
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

On other side, in general, if you want to use interface for type restrictions, you just can create one with the same Equals and GetHashCode methods and add it to any types, that you want to support.

```
public interface IKey
{
    bool Equals(object value);
    int GetHashCode();
}

public struct KeyStruct : IKey
{
}

public class KeyClass :IKey
{
}

public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TKey : IKey
{
}
```

Comment: Using `IKey` will disqualify built-in types like `string` or `int`, won't it?

Comment: Correct, using interface, as I wrote, will add additional type restriction.